# How to insert string in edit control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm going to add string at runtime in edit control,I've tried with different method and strategies but it won't inserted or if inserted but not displayed in edit control!!!
How to make this!please give me solution.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Details please... Show us some code

Answer (score 0):

Use the Windows API `SetWindowText`.

If you have the control use:

```
edit.SetWindowText( _T("Text" ) );
```

Comment: how use that? on control or control's variable

Comment: Sorry! but that API gives an error that Error16 error C2039: 'SetWindowTextW' : is not a member of 'ATL::CStringT<BaseType,StringTraits>'

Comment: The variable "edit" must be a control variable, i.e. a variable of type CEditCtrl, not CString

Comment: I solved!!that was my mistake I used method on variable of that control,it should used on that control only!!